# Count duplicate List<int>

Tags: c#, .net, collections

Count duplicate `List<int>` in `List<List<int>>`.
A duplicate is not order-dependent. { 1, 2, 3 } is a duplicate of { 2, 1, 3 }

Looking for speed without getting silly.

```
public static void CountListTest()
{
    List<List<int>> testData = new List<List<int>>
    {
            new List<int> { 7, 3, 4 },
            new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
            new List<int> { 2, 1, 3 },
            new List<int> { 6, 8, 3 },
            new List<int> { 9, 2, 4 },
            new List<int> { 6, 3, 8 },
            new List<int> { 7, 3, 4 },
    };
    List<List<int>> countList = CountList(testData);
    Debug.WriteLine("");
    testData = new List<List<int>>
    {
            new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
            new List<int> { 2, 1, 3 },
            new List<int> { 6, 8, 3 },
            new List<int> { 2, 1, 3, 9 },
            new List<int> { 6, 8, 3, 9 },
            new List<int> { 2, 1, 3, 9 },
            new List<int> { 9, 2, 4 },
            new List<int> { 6, 3, 8 },
            new List<int> { 7, 3, 4 },
    };
    countList = CountList(testData);
}
public static List<List<int>> CountList(List<List<int>> input)
{
    List<List<int>> returnListList = new List<List<int>>();
    foreach (List<int> list in input)
        list.Sort();
    HashSet<int> alreadyMatched = new HashSet<int>();
    int count = 0;
    bool match = true;
    int lastEval = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (alreadyMatched.Contains(i))
            continue;
        returnListList.Add(input[i]);
        count = 1;
        lastEval = 0;
        for (int j = i+1; j < input.Count; j++)
        {
            if (alreadyMatched.Contains(j))
                continue;
            lastEval = j;
            if (input[i].Count() != input[j].Count())
                continue;
            match = true;
            for (int k = 0; k < input[i].Count(); k++)
            {
                if(input[i][k] != input[j][k])
                {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(match)
            {
                count++;
                alreadyMatched.Add(j);
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Count = {0}  List {1}", count, string.Join(", ", input[i]));
    }
    if (count == 1 && lastEval > 0)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Count = {0}  List {1}", 1, string.Join(", ", input[lastEval]));
        returnListList.Add(input[lastEval]);
    }
    return returnListList;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is also possible to solve the problem using LINQ in combination with a custom comparer:

```
// note: the comparer requires the lists to be sorted
public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<int> x, List<int> y)
    {
        if (x.Count != y.Count)
            return false;           
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
            if (x[i] != y[i]) return false;         
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<int> x) => x.Count;
}
```

And the linq query:

```
IEqualityComparer<List<int>> comparer = new Comparer();
testData.ForEach(l => l.Sort());
var distinctLists = testData
    .GroupBy(i => i, comparer)
    .Select(group => new { List = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });

foreach (var distinctList in distinctLists)
    Console.WriteLine($"Count: {distinctList.Count}; List: ({string.Join(", ", distinctList.List)})");
```

The "LINQ solution" is more readable and a little bit faster than the "manual comparisation". Depending on the actual size of the test set, you can play with the hash function to further improve performance :).

Comment: Really interesting approach - cunning use of `GetHashCode`!

Comment: Thanks :) There are other functions imaginable (e.g. `x.Aggregate(31, (item, agg) => item ^ agg)`), but the comparison of 2 lists is already very fast so that any aggregation function that works on the whole list probably decreases the performance. If the lists have always the same length, an alternative approach may be to use always the first or the last entry as hash...

Comment: Inside the Equals method you could use the linq SequenceEqual method when comparing the list values.

Comment: @denis have you look at the source for sequenceequals?  Does the same thing as the for loop in his equal method using enumerator and exiting first time it doesn't equal.  Granted a for using index method might be a bit faster but I doubt it's noticeable.

Comment: And it is fast.

Answer (score 4):

The code itself is not so bad although it could use more `{}` and maybe more precise names then `lastEval` or `match`. Of course it shouldn't print to the console but return a usable result.

---

I can't tell how fast/slow it would be if it returned a result that can be printed outside the method. I compared it with another search algorithm and for 1.000.000 iterations mine is ~20ms faster.

---

I think the method could do better by returning a dictionary with the results.

Currently the original method runs twice over the item list. First by sorting them and then by searching for duplicates.

This could be improved by using a helper array to mark which item is already sorted and skip subsequent sortings thus run over the items only once.

The last optimization is to skip items that already have been checked. I think you are doing this with the `alreadyMatched` helper but I'm not sure about it.

Making the method generic and require `T` to be `IComparable` makes it possbile to reuse it for other collections with comparable items.

The value comparison takes place in a local function `sequenceEqualFast`.

Similarly it sorts the lists and keeps track of the sorting in the local `sortList` function.

```
public static Dictionary<List<T>, int> FindDuplicatesFast<T>(
    List<List<T>> values
) where T : IComparable
{
    var isDuplicate = new bool[values.Count];
    var isSorted = new bool[values.Count];

    // Key: first of duplicates
    // Value: count of duplicates
    var results = new Dictionary<List<T>, int>();

    var sequenceEqualFast = new Func<List<T>, List<T>, bool>((l1, l2) =>
    {
        if (l1.Count != l2.Count) { return false; }
        for (int k = 0; k < l1.Count(); k++)
        {
            if (l1[k].CompareTo(l2[k]) != 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });

    var sortList = new Action<int>(i =>
    {
        if (!isSorted[i])
        {
            values[i].Sort();
            isSorted[i] = true;
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (isDuplicate[i]) { continue; }
        sortList(i);

        results[values[i]] = 1;
        isDuplicate[i] = true;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < values.Count; j++)
        {
            if (isDuplicate[j]) { continue; }
            sortList(j);

            if (sequenceEqualFast(values[i], values[j]))
            {
                isDuplicate[j] = true;
                results[values[i]] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

---

I have run some more tests and these are the results.

Test collection

```
var rnd = new Random();

var itemCount = 100;
var testData = Enumerable.Range(0, itemCount).Select(e => 
{
    var count = rnd.Next(3, 5);
    return Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(en => rnd.Next(0, 10)).ToList();
}).ToList();

var testCount = 10000;
```

Results

```
@Paparazzi
00:00:03.2791287 

@t3chb0t
00:00:01.6763969
```

Comment: Fails at more than 2 - did you test that?   I just did and it counts 3 just find.  Not sure if alreadyMatched will skip already checked?   When would alreadyMatched fail?

Comment: @Paparazzi yes I did, I attached the results.

Comment: @Paparazzi ah, you mean if I tested your method? well, I'm now confused, I don't know what I've tested anymore... spagetti test code :-P sorry.

Comment: @Paparazzi I'll remove this part from the answer.

Comment: There seem to be language barrier here.  You assert the code in the question fails a condition but when I test it does not fail that condition.

Comment: I don't agree that testing for sorted in a double loop will be more efficient than just sorting once.   For sure it is not as readable.

Comment: @Paparazzi no barrier, I already admitted that I've tested some crap due to my spagetti test code and got wrong results. I edited that part out.

Comment: @Paparazzi well, you'll loose all doubt when you've tested it. Optimized code is never good readable, neither yours nor mine. If you want to have readable code then you should solve it with linq but the performance dropps drastically (I've tested it and it need twice as much time)... and yes, I find my is more readable :-]

Answer (score 3):

**Performance**

- Using the `Count` property instead of the `Count()` method should increase the performance a little bit because it avoids a softcast via `as` and a `null` check.
- Adding a `List<int>` containing the `Count` of the `List<int>` and filled in the sorting loop at the beginning will increase the performance some more, only 2/3 of the execution time as yours.
- Not accessing the lists to compare by index or the items of the lists by `list[listIndex][itemIndex]` will reduce the execution time to 50%.

**Code**

- I have told you about braces in another review, so I won't bother you again with this (just don't cry if you got a hard to track bug) .
- Checking the result/success of a method by writing to `Debug` is the wrong way of doing. Better write some tests. In this way you are on the safe side if you refector your code.
- The loop to compare two lists (the most inner one) should be extracted to a separate method to make the main method shorter and easier to read.
- Using the `var` type if the type of the right hand side of an assignment is obvious will make your code cleaner.
- Using some vertical space (new lines)  will make your code much more readable
- The method name doesn't reflect what the method is doing. The method isn't counting how often a `List` is inside the `input` but returns a `List` containing no duplicates. Maybe `Distinct` or something like this would be better.
- I wouldn't expect if I pass a `List<List<int>>` into that method that the passed in value would be changed, because that what `Array.Sort()` is doing.

Implementing some of the mentioned changes will lead to

```
public static List<List<int>> Distinct(List<List<int>> input)
{
    var returnListList = new List<List<int>>();
    var counts = new List<int>(input.Count);

    foreach (var list in input)
    {
        list.Sort();
        counts.Add(list.Count);
    }

    var alreadyMatched = new HashSet<int>();
    int count = 0;
    int lastEval = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (alreadyMatched.Contains(i))
        {
            continue;
        }

        returnListList.Add(input[i]);
        count = 1;
        lastEval = 0;

        var current = input[i];

        for (int j = i + 1; j < input.Count; j++)
        {
            if (alreadyMatched.Contains(j))
            {
                continue;
            }

            lastEval = j;

            if (counts[i] != counts[j])
            {
                continue;
            }

            var compareAgainst = input[j];

            if (AreSame(current, compareAgainst))
            {
                count++;
                alreadyMatched.Add(j);
            }
        }
    }

    if (count == 1 && lastEval > 0)
    {
        returnListList.Add(input[lastEval]);
    }

    return returnListList;
}


private static bool AreSame(List<int> first, List<int> second)
{
    // The Count properties of the lists are already checked and the same
    for (int k = 0; k < first.Count; k++)
    {
        if (first[k] != second[k])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

A simple `Clone` method to avoid the changing of the input parameter to be implemented by yourself

```
private static List<List<int>> Clone(List<List<int>> source)
{
    var cloned = new List<List<int>>(source.Count);

    foreach (var list in source)
    {
        cloned.Add(new List<int>(list));
    }

    return cloned;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is faster and even got a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

The type of data that you are desiring to return by be better served using LINQ with [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) to flatten the nested lists then leveraging [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var duplicates = testData.SelectMany(s => s).GroupBy(g => g)
        .Select(s => new { Key = s.Key, Count = s.Count()})
        .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
        .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Count);
```

Comment: Did you test because I am not getting what I consider a correct answer?

Comment: I did do a quick test via LINQPad and basically got back a dictionary where the Key was the number and the value was the number of occurrences of that number across all the lists.

Comment: Could you add a test method and output to your answer?

Comment: I put a running sample of what I saw here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/kEmzIB

Comment: That output is not correct.   Compare it to the output from the posted working solution.

Comment: A duplicate is an entire list equal to other list. This example however searches for value duplicates.